# Can I see parameter values later than 30 minutes in Firebase reporting?

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

For custom events in Firebase reporting I can see their parameters, but some of those parameters have values. I am able to see values of these paramters only in the last 30 minutes as seen in the screenshot. Is there a way to see the cumulative data of parameter values for longer than 30 minutes? I tried adding parameters as custom metrics but still their value doesn't show in dashboards/reports.